# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'trackerId', table 'History'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: hibernate, null, foreign-keys

I'm trying to save a History entity to the db. On that entity is also a 'trackerId' which causing the problem. The History table:

[image]
And here the History entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "History")
public class History {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3729158137942963422L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "absenceStatus")
    private Integer absenceStatus;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name = "absenceTypeId", nullable = false )
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_History_AbsenceType")
    private AbsenceType absenceType;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name = "weekId", nullable = false )
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_History_WeeklyOverview")
    private WeeklyOverview weeklyOverview;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name = "trackerId" )
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_History_Tracker")
    private WeeklyOverviewTracker weeklyOverviewTracker;
...
```

What I'm doing in the code:
Saving a WeeklyOverview and a WeeklyOverviewTracker. After that (commit is done) I get the previously saved WeeklyOverviewTracker entity and add it on the WeeklyOverview. Then passing this WeeklyOverview as parameter in the save method of the History entity. And before saving History, I'm reading the WeeklyOverviewTracker entity from the WeeklyOverview and add it to the History entity. The ID of the WeeklyOverviewTracker is not null and has the correct ID.

I really can't see the problem, especially because the ID is set on WeeklyOverviewTracker.

If I'm adding a 'nullable = false' to the @JoinColumn(name = "trackerId" ), then I get this error while saving:

> TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a
>   transient value - transient instance must be saved before current
>   operation

If I then add a Cascade.ALL I'm ending up with two WeeklyOverviewTracker records on the db...

Code that results in a TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value:

```
    private WeeklyOverviewDTO saveWeeklyOverviewDTOWithTracker(...) { 
      WeeklyOverview weeklyOverview = WeeklyOverviewConverter.from(woDTO);
      weeklyOverview = weeklyOverviewDAO.merge(weeklyOverview);
      WeeklyOverviewTracker savedWeeklyOverviewTracker = saveWeeklyOverviewTracker(...);
      WeeklyOverviewDTO weeklyOverviewDTO = WeeklyOverviewConverter.from(weeklyOverview);

      List<WeeklyOverviewTrackerDTO> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
      WeeklyOverviewTrackerDTO weeklyOverviewTrackerDTO = WeeklyOverviewTrackerConverter.fromEntity( savedWeeklyOverviewTracker );
      tmp.add( weeklyOverviewTrackerDTO );
      weeklyOverviewDTO.setWeeklyOverviewTrackerDTOs( tmp );

      return weeklyOverviewDTO;
}
```

After this method finishs, the transaction will be commited and a new one starts to save the History entity:

```
        public List<HistoryDTO> save( WeeklyOverviewDTO weeklyOverviewDTO ) {
                final List<HistoryDTO> historyDTOs = createHistoryDTOs( weeklyOverviewDTO );

                List<History> updatedHistories = new ArrayList<>(); 

                for( final HistoryDTO dto : HistoryDTOs ) {
                    History updated = transactionWrapper(new IPersistenceExecutable<History>() {
                        @Override
                        public History execute() {
                          boolean contains1 = historyDAO.getEntityManager().contains( entity.getAbsenceType() );
                          boolean contains2 = historyDAO.getEntityManager().contains( entity.getWeeklyOverview() );
                          boolean contains3 = historyDAO.getEntityManager().contains( entity.getWeeklyOverviewTracker() );
                          History merged = historyDAO.merge( HistoryConverter.toEntity( dto ) );
    ...
```

and the createHistoryDTOs method is just creating the HistoryDTO and set the WO-DTO, AbsenceTypeDTO and WOT-DTO on it. And it retrieves all this data from the WO-DTO.

I just added the check with the contains. So contains 1 and 2 are true. Contains 3 is false.

edit:
Ah, I think I got it. The `HistoryConverter.toEntity( dto )` is converting the AbsenceTypeDTO, WeeklyOverviewDTO and WeeklyOverviewTrackerDTO to an entity and add them to the History entity. But before converting the DTOs it checks if an ID is present, if yes a find() is called. And that part was missing for the WeeklyOverviewTracker...

Will test tomorrow and let you know...

Comment: It could be the instance is detached. Try to reread it by id just before setting to history.

Comment: Ok, that worked. But why does it not work as soon as I read it from the DB, convert the entity to a DTO and later back to an entity and then save it? I was thinking that only the ID of the entity matters?

Comment: As soo as the Entity leaves open transaction scope it becomes detached. The same happens if you create it from scratch. Instead of proxied entity (with reference to session etc) you have just POJO class. So the error says it's transient and need to be saved to be attached to the session (the session is new). Reread from DB returns already attached one.

Comment: Ok, so my problem was/is that I'm fetching a record from the DB after the WeeklyOverview and the WeeklyOverviewTracker are saved and wanted to use it later? As soon as the transaction in which the WO and WOT are saved is closed, the fetched entity is in a detached state?

Comment: Yes. And you need to reattach the entity. The simplest way is to reread from DB.

Comment: And I can also not use the entity returned by the saveWOT method and add it to the WO-DTO and reuse it later (after commit) while saving the History entity? But why? I also have the WO-DTO and set it on the History later and save it. Why is it a problem with WOT but not with WO?

Comment: I can only guess without seeing the code.

Comment: I added the relevant code snippets.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].